# Django bulk updating via F

Tags: django

I am trying to bulk update a number of objects for a given model. I figured I could do this via a dictionary together with F doing something like

```
FooBar.objects.filter(...).update(order = order_dict[F('id')])
```

where order_dict is something like

```
{1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 4}
```

objects with id equal to 1, 2, 3, and 4 exist but it is giving me a key error: F(id) nonetheless. Why precisely does this not work? And is there some way to achieve this other than updating objects one by one or using a 3th party package?

Comment: That is not possible that way, since the updating happens at the database level, and thus you can  not "inject" Python functions.

Comment: You can use a `Case(..)` and encode the dictionary as a cascade of `When(..)` cases, but this makes it very "ugly"...

Comment: I think you are looking for https://github.com/bfirsh/django-ordered-model which will help solve your problem of reordering